# call a Php function using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Am new in php, so please explain   me this code,I want to call a Php function using this code,is it possible,and my function name is remove_db();(no parameters) ,
What is the myphpscript.php?
Please explain.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function compute() {
        var params="session=123";
        $.post('myphpscript.php',params,function(data) { 
            alert(data); //for testing if data is being fetched
            var myObject = eval('(' + data + ')');
            document.getElementById("result").value = myObject(addend_1,addend_2);
        }); 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Learn about HTTP protocol :))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP (or other server side) code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor)

Answer (score 1):

You can NOT call a PHPfunction from javascript. Javascript is CLIENTside (=executes in the browser) and PHP is SERVERside (=executed on server).

Php has llready done its job, and sent everything to the browser, therefor it cant do anything

This is where the AJAX comes in. The ajax sends a request to a phpfile. The php gets executed on the server and gives javascript the result(if any).

You need to put the php function in that file to be executed (just as php works). If you want to send some info to php, use that `data` option, which is explained in the jQuery documentation

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) calls ([jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)).

Another library that I've found useful is [XAJAX](http://www.xajax-project.org) it makes AJAX calls to PHP functions nice and easy.

Answer (score -1):

you can call `php` function in `json` object .
for example:

i want to show a `captcha`, and my `captcha` is created by a `php` function,
so in my `javascript` code I use this codes:

```
     var $img = $("#form_img);
     $img.attr("src", "/json-req:path\to\phpfile?req=" + escape("{\"id\":1, 
    \"method\":\"method name\", \"params\": [\"parameter\"]}"));
```

Comment: this answer is wrong, you never ever can call a php function from javascript or html , you can only call a php FILE, not a FUNCTION.
look at @martijn 's answer

Comment: sorry for my answer,i understood wrong your question,i offer you see this framework,it could help you.http://sourceforge.net/projects/pome-framework/